# Controlar atributo contraseña con CHECK Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

tengo una tabla que contiene `Usuario` y  `Contraseña`

Para cada uno se deberá determinar: usuario de logueo (único en el sistema e identificatorio) y
contraseña de acceso (la cual debe contener 5 letras y 2 números – largo exacto 7). Tomar en cuenta
que el nombre de logueo debe tener 10 caracteres exactamente

La tabla creada es la siguiente:

```
    create table Empleado(
    Usuario varchar (10) not null unique CHECK(len([Usuario])=10),
    Contraseña varchar (7) not null CHECK (len([Contraseña])=(7) AND [Contraseña] like '%[0-9]%' AND [Contraseña] like '%[A-Z]%')
    )
```

Y los datos que inserto son:

```
   insert into Empleado(Usuario, Contraseña) Values ('santiago21', 'qwerty1')
   insert into Empleado(Usuario, Contraseña) Values ('FaaacuuUwU', 'qwertY1')
```

El problema es que el segundo insert debería tomarlo, pero el primero no, cosa que **NO** hace,
alguno sabe como debería hacerlo?, Gracias.

Comment: Esa validación debe de hacerse en el front-end, y a la base de datos la contraseña debe llegar encriptada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para tener en cuenta la contraseña, puedes validar el chequeo mediante una función.

```
Create function dbo.idValidPassword (@texto varchar(7))
Returns bit
With schemabinding -- No alterar la tabla
Begin
    declare @isValid bit;
With R as (
-- 7 digitos
    Select 1 n 
    from
        (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) Tbl(n)),
R2 as (
-- numeramos
    Select Row_number()over(order by (Select null)) as row
        From R
    ),
IndChars As (
-- extraemos los digitos.
    Select Substring(@texto,r2.row,1) as myChar
    from r2),
Cumplen as (
    Select  case when i.myChar like '[0-9]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isNumber, -- es un número
            case when i.myChar like '[A-Z]' THEN 1 else 0 END AS isLetter -- es una letra
    from IndChars i
), validos as (
Select sum(isNumber) as numbers, sum(isLetter) as letters 
From Cumplen 
)
Select @isValid = case when numbers = 2 and letters = 5 then 1 else 0 end
from validos;

Return @isValid;
End;
```

La función, sobre el parámetro que reciba como entrada, lo divide en caracteres y cuenta, cuanto son números y cuantos son letras. Si esto encaja en lo solicitado, devuelve 1 sino 0.

Ahora en la definición de la tabla.

```
create table Empleado(
    Usuario varchar(10) not null unique CHECK (len(Usuario)=10),
-- Mencionamos la función para la columna
    Contraseña varchar (7) not null CHECK (len(Contraseña)=7 and dbo.idValidPassword(Contraseña) = 1)
);
go
```

Comment: Wow, muchas por tu ayuda!